# pantalla en blanco al agregar una nueva variable en la comparación PHP

Tags: php

Hola a todos muy buenas tardes.

En mi código actual de que procesa un archivo excel tengo una comparación de una variable la cual hace el proceso correctamente, el problema me ocurre cuando intento comparar la consulta con más de una variable se queda en blanco la pantalla no recibe ningún valor.

Acá les explico mucho mejor:

Este es mi archivo almacen.php allí tengo el formulario para enviar al procesar.

```
<form action="iexcesin.php" method="post" name="frmExcelImport" id="frmExcelImport" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<br>

<input type="file" name="file" id="file-1" accept=".csv"/>
     
<br>                
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="import" value="GUARDAR">
</center>
</form>
```

Y el archivo que recibe el CSV y lo procesa es: iexcesin.php

Este archivo es el que me esta generando el error al momento de hacer lo siguiente (los comentarios los voy agregar dentro del mismo código comentado para que sepan en donde me genera el problema)

```
<?php
require('conexiones.php');

$tipo       = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$tamanio    = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$archivotmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$lineas     = file($archivotmp);

$i = 0;

foreach ($lineas as $linea) {
    $cantidad_registros = count($lineas);
    $cantidad_regist_agregados =  ($cantidad_registros - 1);

    if ($i != 0) {

    $datos = explode(";", $linea);

//aquí tengo 3 variables las cuales se reciben desde el CSV. codigo, cantidad y ubicación
//Esta última variable que se llama ubicación cuando la agrego es donde me genera el problema
       
    $codigo                = !empty($datos[0])  ? ($datos[0]) : '';
    $cantidad              = (int)$datos[1];
    $ubicacion             = $datos[2];
       
    if( !empty($codigo) ){
        $sqlVerificarExistencia = ("SELECT codigo_reci,canti_recibidos,ubi FROM recibir_items WHERE codigo_reci='".($codigo)."' AND ubi='".($ubicacion)."'");
        $queryDuplicidad        = mysqli_query($cn, $sqlVerificarExistencia);
        $cantidadDuplicidad     = mysqli_num_rows($queryDuplicidad);
        $DataDuplicidad  = mysqli_fetch_array($queryDuplicidad);
        
    if($cantidadDuplicidad >0){ 
    if ( $DataDuplicidad['canti_recibidos'] >0) { 

    $cantBD     = $DataDuplicidad['canti_recibidos'];
    $cantiTotal = ($cantBD - $cantidad);

    $updateData =  ("UPDATE recibir_items SET 
        canti_recibidos='" .$cantiTotal. "'
        WHERE codigo_reci='".$codigo."' AND ubi='".$ubicacion."'
    ");
    $resultadoUpdate = mysqli_query($cn, $updateData);
    
    
    echo "<script>alert('Productos descontados correctamente!')
                     window.location='almacen.php';</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('El descuento fue correctamente')
                         window.location='almacen.php';</script>";
    } 
    }
    
  } //Cierre de mi 2 If
  } //Cierre de mi 1 If

    $i++;
}


?>
```

No se cual puede ser el error ya que he revisado esto unas 80 veces, cuando hago el cargue del CSV y pasa al archivo iexcesin.php funciona bien si le quito la variable ubicacion en todos lados.

El problema es cuando la agrego.

Cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Y que problema aparece? ¿No hace el update o muestra un mensaje de error, o guarda valores erróneamente?...

Comment: Sale que no recibio valores, pero en realidad si coloco la misma consulta en MySQL si funciona bien con el filtro de ubicacion.

Comment: Si no te da mensajes de error y no funciona al usar $ubicacion, la pregunta es obvia ¿has comprobado que el valor de $ubicacion es correcto? También puede asignar a $ubicacion un valor concreto (no extraído del CSV) con el que SELECT tenga que devolver algo.

Comment: Si e verificado y el dato que busco por la variable de ubicacion es correcto, de hecho hago la misma consulta directo en phpmyadmin y si funciona, pero en el código no me funciona. super raro.

Comment: Toca debug a fondo. Si tienes debugger usas plos breakpoins y si no pues echos y exit. Justo antes de if($cantidadDuplicidad >0), yo pondría un print_r para ver la variable $sqlVerificarExistencia (el SELECT),  $DataDuplicidad  y $cantidadDuplicidad. Ese select literal lo probaría en directo sobre la base de datos. Y a ver que pasa.

Comment: Voy hacer eso y te cuento.

Comment: Hola despues de intentar muchas cosas puedo deducir que el error es al comparar con la variable $ubicacion = $datos[2]; esta variable es de tipo varchar puede que eso me este ocasionando el error, existe alguna de resolverlo?